# Angular Material, mat-list-item & routerLinkActive doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I have this navigation view, using `MatSidenavModule`. The problem i'm facing is in mobile screens, when i click a `mat-list-item`, `mat-sidenav` closes as expected, but when i open `mat-sidenav`, always the first item in list is marked by Material as active. If i use a `div` it works as expected (red colored). The problem is when i use `mat-list-item`. I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

```js
<mat-sidenav-container [hasBackdrop]="false">

    <mat-sidenav 
        #sidenav [mode]="windowInnerWidth > 1200 ? 'side' : 'push'" 
        [opened]="windowInnerWidth > 1200 ? true : false" 
        >
        <div class="mat-typography">
            <h2>Material</h2>
        </div>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <mat-nav-list>

            <!-- it does not work -->
            <mat-list-item 
                *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems"
                [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]"
                routerLinkActive="router-active"
                (click)="windowInnerWidth < 1200 ? sidenav.close() : null">
                <span matListItemTitle>{{menuItem.title}}</span>
            </mat-list-item>

            <!-- it works -->
            <div *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems"
                [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]"
                routerLinkActive="router-active"
                (click)="windowInnerWidth < 1200 ? sidenav.close() : null">
                {{menuItem.title}}
            </div>
        </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <app-toolbar [windowInnerWidth]="windowInnerWidth" (toggleEvent)="toggleSidenav()"></app-toolbar>
        <div class="router-outlet-container">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>     
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

```css
.router-active {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I am noticing that the problem is also found on the official angular material page: https://material.angular.io/components/core/overview

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it this way. I hope this helps someone:

```css
.menu-link {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    padding: 20px 0px;
}

mat-list-item.router-active {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" (click)="windowInnerWidth < 1200 ? sidenav.close() : null" routerLinkActive="router-active">
  <mat-icon matListItemIcon *ngIf="menuItem.icon" class="menu-item-icon">{{menuItem.icon}}</mat-icon>
  <a class="menu-link" [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]">
    <span matLine>{{menuItem.title}}</span>
  </a>
</mat-list-item>
```